# R - Count Number of Rows w/ @ Symbol

Tags: regex, r

I have a list of records with IDs (some of which are usernames and some of which are email addresses). I'd like to know how many are email addresses. I was thinking an easy way to do this would be count how many of the rows contain the @ symbol but I can't get a function to work to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Sample dataset:

```
x <- c("1234@aol.com", "johnnyApple", "tomb@gmail.com")
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341554/regular-expression-in-base-r-regex-to-identify-email-address

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both answers so far are entirely correct, but if you're looking for an email address, a method that's less likely to have false positives is:

```
x <- c("1234@aol.com", "johnnyApple", "tomb@gmail.com")  
sum(regexpr(".*@.*\\..*",x) != -1)
```

Comment: You could even go further and require ".com", ".edu" etc, although then you risk false negatives.

Comment: Good thinking... Though more like `sum(regexpr(".*@.*\\..*",x) != -1)` probably to match OPs desired output. A similar approach could be `sum(sub(".*(@).*\\..*", "\\1", x) == "@")`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
x <- c("1234@aol.com", "johnnyApple", "tomb@gmail.com")
sum(grepl("@", x))
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming you data is `df`,  you can try

```
length(grep(pattern="@", df$V1))
[1] 2
```